# Conditional rendering elements in object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is conditionally rendering of  one element in my object, i.e. if the `chosenHour` key (inside `hoursInfo` array) equals to `19:30` then I'd like to have this whole element not to be rendered, so I would have just two elements instead of three.

The problem is that IFE returns `null` if the condition is not met so I still have object of three elements with second element of `null`. All is done in React so I thought it is good idea to use IFE in order to use if statement without else part.

Here's my code:

```
bookingObjToSend = {
    name, email, phone, kidsNo, adultsNo, fullDate, year, month, day, chosenRoom,
    hoursInfo: [
        { chosenHour: 
            chosenHour ==='9:30' ? '9:15' :
            chosenHour ==='12:00' ? '12:15' :
            chosenHour ==='14:30' ? '13:45' :
            chosenHour ==='17:00' ? '16:45' :
            chosenHour ==='19:30' ? '19:45' : null ,
         renderedByBirthday: true, isBirthday: false },
        (() => {
            if(chosenHour !== '19:30'){ return { chosenHour:                         
                chosenHour ==='9:30' ? '10:45' :
                chosenHour ==='12:00' ? '13:45' :
                chosenHour ==='14:30' ? '15:15' :
                chosenHour ==='17:00' ? '18:15' :
                null ,
             renderedByBirthday: true, isBirthday: false}}
        })(),
        { chosenHour, isBirthday: true}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out all falsy elements from the array to get rid of the potential `null` values.

```
bookingObjToSend = {
    name, email, phone, kidsNo, adultsNo, fullDate, year, month, day, chosenRoom,
    hoursInfo: [
        { chosenHour: 
            chosenHour ==='9:30' ? '9:15' :
            chosenHour ==='12:00' ? '12:15' :
            chosenHour ==='14:30' ? '13:45' :
            chosenHour ==='17:00' ? '16:45' :
            chosenHour ==='19:30' ? '19:45' : null ,
         renderedByBirthday: true, isBirthday: false },
        (() => {
            if(chosenHour !== '19:30'){ return { chosenHour:                         
                chosenHour ==='9:30' ? '10:45' :
                chosenHour ==='12:00' ? '13:45' :
                chosenHour ==='14:30' ? '15:15' :
                chosenHour ==='17:00' ? '18:15' :
                null ,
             renderedByBirthday: true, isBirthday: false}}
        })(),
        { chosenHour, isBirthday: true}
    ].filter(Boolean)
}
```